# Debugging grunt with Intellij

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, gruntjs, webstorm

I'm trying to debug grunt with Intellij (IDEA).
The technologies are: NodeJS, express, AngularJS.

The problem:
Debugger does not stop on breakpoints.

I'll be happy to hear your thoughts.

configuration tab:
Node interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Javscript file: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt

Browser / Live Edit tab:

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

and here is the Gruntfile.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    express: {
        dev: {
            options: {
                script: 'server.js'
            }
        },
    },
    watch: {
        html: {
            files: [ '**/*.html'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        server: {
            files: [ 'server.js'],
            tasks: ['express:dev'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
                spawn: false // Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
            }
        },
        js: {
            files: [ '**/*.js'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        }
    },
    open: {
        express: {
            // Gets the port from the connect configuration
            path: 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    }

});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['express:dev', 'watch' ])
```

};

Comment: I've the same issue. In the options of express.dev, set background: true and it should work. But your next task won't run because the express server will run in the same process as grunt.
Here are some threads where I've posted my problem: https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/27
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976584/node-js-server-debuging-with-webstorm-grunt

Comment: [WEB-11140](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11140) is fixed in WebStorm8, so debugging should work out of the box (no need to modify grunt-express-server sources)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just tried a sample Angular+Express application run as a Grunt task. I've used your Gruntfile.js (unchanged). My Node.js Run configuration looks as fololows:

configuration tab:
 Node interpreter: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
 Javscript file: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt
 Working directory: my project root - the folder where Gruntfile.js is located

Live Edit tab:
 After launch enabled
 with JavaScript Debugger enabled

```
http://localhost:3000
```

I set breakpoints in my controllers.js and run the configuration above in debugger => breakpoints in Angular code work as expected. Breakpoints in my server code don't :)

To get breakpoints in server-side code working, I did the following:

- added 'debug: true' to dev options in Gruntfile.js:

express: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    script: 'server.js',
                    debug: true
                }
            }
        },

- modified the node_modules\grunt-express-server\tasks\lib\server.js, line 65, changing '--debug' to '--debug-brk=' ('--debug-brk=47977' in my case)

Answer (score 2):

Try installing the JetBrains IDE Support extension for chrome, and then create a javascript Debug configuration like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ignaciosuay.com](http://ignaciosuay.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/setConfig.png))</sub>

My grunt server is running in the port 9000, so change it for 3000.
note: You need to run grunt before running this configuration.
If you have any query, please have a look to this [post](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-debug-angularjs-with-intellij/) where is explained step by step how to debug AngularJS with Intellij.