# Grunt Server and WebStorm javascript debugging (and SpyJS) not working

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, webstorm

I have an app that I made with yeoman, grunt an angular JS (typical setup - image included below). I'm trying to debug my project with spyjs (or even regular javascript debugging) but I can't seem to get it working when I run "grunt serve" - the file that's loaded from WebStorm clearly isn't going through the grunt server (but localhost:63343 instead). Any ideas how I could configure things properly to get debugging to work?

[image: My WebStorm/ AngularJS Setup]

Here's my SpyJS configuration:

[image: My SpyJs Configuration]

I've also tried localhost:9000 for the URL to trace (which is the port that grunt serve runs on), and I've tried using another node interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

You need using the server your client code runs on (`localhost:3000`) and not WebStorm built-in webserver to debug your Angular application served by Grunt. See [Debugging grunt with Intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957411/debugging-grunt-with-intellij) for some hints
Note: haven't tried this with spyjs - only with a regular debugger

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to Webstorm 9. As per [spy-js](http://spy-js.com/)

> Node.js tracing is now supported in WebStorm 9 EAP, including multi process and node cluster tracing support.

Then instead of using `Spy-js` profile, use `Spy-js for Node.js` profile.

This screenshot is from Webstorm 9 RC.

[image]

Comment: What is the cli.js file?

Comment: The entry point to your app. Could be `index.js` or `server.js` or anything that runs the app.

Answer (score 1):

I am using too the Yeoman generator (AngularJs + grunt), and I am debugging the application using the JavaScript Debug configuration like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [ignaciosuay.com](http://ignaciosuay.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/setConfig.png))</sub>

Have a look to this [post](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-debug-angularjs-with-intellij/) about how to debug angularJS with Intellij (It should work too for web storm)