# Webstorm Debugger Does not Connect to Angular Application

Tags: angularjs, debugging, webstorm

I am trying to debug an Angular application using IntelliJ Webstorm (10.0.1). I created an application with Yeoman (1.4.6) using the command `yo angular`. I then opened the directory as a project in Webstorm. (This is the same configuration as described in ["Grunt Server and WebStorm javascript debugging (and SpyJS) not working"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671576/grunt-server-and-webstorm-javascript-debugging-and-spyjs-not-working).) I can run the application using `grunt serve` both from the command line and from within Webstorm. I now want to set breakpoints and step through the Javascript in Webstorm.

I followed the instructions in [How to debug AngularJS with Intellij](http://ignaciosuay.com/how-to-debug-angularjs-with-intellij/), but debugging still does not work. Specifically, I start the app with `grunt serve` and then try to connect with my debug configuration, but the debugger never connects. The Debugger window in Webstorm reads "Waiting for connection from JetBrains IDE Support Extension for Chrome (IDE port 63342)."

- I am on OS X (10.10.2). My default browser is Chrome (41.0.2272.118). The JetBrains IDE Support extension (2.0.7) is installed and enabled in the browser. It is using the default port 63342.
- My Angular application is running in the default location http://localhost:9000.
- In the debug configuration, my "URL" is http://localhost:9000/ and I map the index.html in my project to the "Remote URL" http://localhost:9000/index.html.

I am asking this separately from the other Webstorm debugging questions on StackOverflow because those do not mention the "Waiting for connection" message and their solutions are to follow the instructions that I started from.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?