# Using intellij to debug a project with Grunt

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, gruntjs

I use intellij with a mean stack and i want to debug the js file of my server.
Until now, i launch "grunt serve" in a line command from the directory where my project is and i have no problem.

In intellij there is two way to debug a project with nodejs. You can use the remote debug configuration. This way is working but not very confortable. you have to stop the debugguer each time you made a change in your js files and you have to restart the debugguer....

Or you can configure a GruntJs configuration.

I try to use this way but i don't have the same behavior that i have when i launch "grunt serve" in a terminal from the project directory. The process stuck at the "concurrent:server".

this is my configuration from intellij : [image]

And this is the line command generated by intellij

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=36118 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /home/bryan/Documents/projects/subscriptions/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt --gruntfile /home/bryan/Documents/projects/subscriptions/subscriptions/Gruntfile.js -v -d serve
```

So my question is : What's the difference between using "grunt serve" in a terminal or using a grunt debug configuration from intelliJ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found theses links from intelliJ Support

Solution :

```
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206320279-AngularJS-debug-grunt-server-hangs-at-Running-concurrent-server-concurrent-task
```

Explanation :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252310/how-to-fork-a-child-process-that-listens-on-a-different-debug-port-than-the-pare
```

> The problem is likely caused by the way Grunt spawns child tasks. By  >default, the spawned child process uses the same debug port as a parent  >process - as a result the forked process is suspended and the  >application 'stalls'. See >http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252310/how-to-fork-a-child-process->that-listens-on-a-different-debug-port-than-the-pare, for example.
>   Please try adding process.execArgv = []; at the top of the gruntfile.js
>   at the top of your Gruntfile.js - does it help?

And yes adding process.execArgv = [] at the top of GruntFile.js remove the stuck of "concurrent:serve" but my breakpoints don't work on port:5858

before overwritting process.execArgv here is content :

```
[ '--debug-brk=40305', '--expose_debug_as=v8debug' ]
```

At the start of the "grunt serve" i have this :

```
/usr/bin/node --debug-brk=40305 --expose_debug_as=v8debug /home/bryan/Documents/projects/subscriptions/node_modules/grunt/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt --gruntfile /home/bryan/Documents/projects/subscriptions/subscriptions/Gruntfile.js serve
debugger listening on port 40305
Running "serve" task
```

And at the end :

```
Running "express:dev" (express) task
Stopping Express server
Starting background Express server
debugger listening on port 5858
Express server listening on 9000, in development mode
```

In the intellij debugger variables panel its show **"Connected to localhost:40305"**

When i use a second debug configuration with nodejs debug remote on port :5858 breakpoints are working but this is ugly as i have described in my first question.

i tried this solution but nothings changes :

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957411/debugging-grunt-with-intellij?rq=1
```

my gruntfiles already own theses properties :

```
express: { dev: { options: { script: 'app/server.js', debug: true } } },
```

and theses modifications at line 71 in this file node_modules\grunt-express-server\tasks\lib\server.js, changing '--debug' to '--debug-brk='don't affect debugging.